# NestJS GRPC metadata no longer received by server after @grpc/grpc-js update

Tags: node.js, nestjs, grpc

The package `grpc` is being depreciated so i have moved to `@grpc/grpc-js` as advised by the maintainers. Since moving to the new package NestJs no longer receives the metadata in the `ExecutionContext` the following code has worked fine up until the switch.

The server uses `@grpc/grpc-js` like so:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Metadata, status } from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import { RpcException } from '@nestjs/microservices';

export interface IUserDecorator {
  clientId: string;
}

export const User = createParamDecorator(
  (data, context: ExecutionContext): IUserDecorator => {
    const metadata = context.switchToRpc().getContext() as Metadata;
    const { clientid } = metadata.getMap();

    if (!clientid) {
      throw new RpcException({
        code: status.UNAUTHENTICATED,
        message: 'clientId is required',
      });
    }

    return {
      clientId: clientid.toString(),
    };
  },
);
```

The Client constructs metadata like so:

```
import * as GRPC from '@grpc/grpc-js';

const meta = new GRPC.Metadata();
meta.add("clientId", "dasd");
```

constructing meta data in this way produces the following object

```
Metadata { internalRepr: Map { 'clientid' => [Array] }, options: {} }
```

The server does not receive the set meta

```
   // console.log context.switchToRpc().getContext()

   {
        "_internal_repr": {
            "user-agent": [
                "grpc-node/1.24.4 grpc-c/8.0.0 (osx; chttp2; ganges)"
            ]
        },
        "flags": 0
    },
```

however when i cunstruct metadata with the old `grpc` package the server correctly receives metadata.

```
import { Metadata } from 'grpc'
const goodMets = new Metadata();
goodMets.add('clientId', 'dasd');
```

produces

```
Metadata { _internal_repr: { clientid: [Array] }, flags: 0 }
```

server receives

```
    {
        "_internal_repr": {
            "clientid": [
                "dasd"
            ],
            "user-agent": [
                "grpc-node/1.24.4 grpc-c/8.0.0 (osx; chttp2; ganges)"
            ]
        },
        "flags": 0
    },
```

I naively tried to add the meta as snake case (almost certain it wouldn't work, but you know ... got to try)

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. So i have upgraded **nestjs@7 to nestjs@8.** to make it work.

eg. if you look into metadata, user-agent is **grpc-node/1.24.6** its actually coming from **grpc** package.

Answer (score 0):

In client. You can try changing `add` to `set` metadata. It's work fine to me in both version.

Example:

```rb
import * as GRPC from '@grpc/grpc-js';

const meta = new GRPC.Metadata();
meta.set("clientId", "dasd");
```

Answer (score -1):

The change you made here wouldn't actually switch to the new grpc-js package. It just tries to use the `Metadata` class from grpc-js with the `grpc` package used internally within NestJS. NestJS would need to change its dependency on `grpc` to `@grpc/grpc-js` in order to actually switch.